# How to get docker build to show steps performed inside intermediate containers

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-build

I was wondering if there was a way to see each and every step executed in a dockerfile build, in the console output, especially steps that are executed for intermediate containers.

Problem is, for intermediate containers, it just shows "Removing intermediate containers" skipping all individual steps for it.

Comment: Even with the newer BuildKit backend, every Dockerfile line gets printed to the console.  What output are you missing?

Comment: I am new to docker, and I apologize if this is a redundant question, but I have this dockerfile, which has a build and a base section from which publish and final are created respectively. At docker build I specify base as the target. The output shown is only of base and the rest are shown as removed intermediate containers. The build command used is Visual Studio generated. Whilst writing this comment I seem to have stumbled on the solution myself. I removed the target base flag and that seems to shown the console output I was looking for. Thanks David